# dataoutputstream format not correct

Tags: java, netbeans

I am writing a output file using netbeans. I am using dataoutputstream. It outputs the dataset that i want, but it is doing it in one long row. I want it in a column. I've tried to correct it with "n", "t" and System.getProperty("line.separator"). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The DataOutputStream is a way to portably transport data from one application to another. It creates computer readable output and its output is not made for human consumption.

I recommend using a class from the Writer family to create human readable output of your data.